# What's the fastest way to get a local file into an Amazon EBS Volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been using multi-part upload to get a 200+GB file into S3.  Then I have to download that into an EBS volume via the web interface.  Is there a more efficient way than this?

Comment: I doubt you can download an S3 object into an EBS volume using the AWS console web interface.

Comment: I was doing it in Windows via RDP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A**

It might be faster and easier to copy the file to a hard drive and ship the physical media to Amazon using the AWS Import/Export service:

> http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/

AWS will then copy the contents into S3 or an EBS volume as you specify, and ship the disk back to you.

**Option B**

Here's another approach that I would recommend testing:

1. break the file into multiple pieces (e.g., using "split")
2. create an EBS volume and attach to a running EC2 instance (largish to get the high bandwidth)
3. rsync the pieces using compression (-z) with multiple rsync processes running in parallel.  *It's critical to have multiple in parallel to get around the latency issues that will slow down the transfer otherwise.*
4. paste the pieces back into a single file on the target EBS volume (e.g., using "cat")

Comment: It'd be nice if this was a service or SDK somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the EBS volume to an EC2 instance and run an FTP server on that instance. Point the FTP server to the attached EBS volume, then just FTP up your file - it will be written directly to the EBS volume.

You would want to use an FTP server and client that can support resuming interrupted transfers - for example, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have the EBS attached to an EC2 instance and just `rsync` the file up? `rsync` allows you to do everything from compression to autocomplete if the file transmission disconnects before finishing.

`rsync -a --progress myfile ec2-50-19-445-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/`